# Make glossary constant value show

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

Ho-ho-hi, so I have this glossary entry:

```
\newglossaryentry{fermiconstant}{
name={Fermi Coupling Constant},
description={coupling associated to the effective four point interaction of the electroweak interactions},
symbol={\ensuremath{G_F}},
user1={${1.1663787(6)\times 10^{−5}~\text{GeV}^{-2}}$}
}
```

But it does not display the value stored in `user1`. Is there a particular setting needed to show the value, or does anybody have a better way of displaying a glossary constant

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to eproduce the output you currently get. A description/sketch of how the expected output should look like, would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own glossary style where the `user1` value is printed. The value is displayed using the macro `\glsuseri`.

You can define the glossary style any way you like, for example as a table. The example below shows a simple list style (basically `\item[label] definition`). The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) (section 27 and 28) has some more examples of glossary style definitions, and the package also provides [sample files](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples) with style definitions.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbols,nomain]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossarystyle
{symval}% style name
{% based on list style
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
          \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}\space}{}%
          \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
       \ifglshasfield{useri}{##1}{(\glsuseri{##1})}{}%
       \glspar\glossentrydesc{##1}\space(page\space##2)%
       }%
}

\newglossaryentry{fermiconstant}{
name={Fermi Coupling Constant},
description={coupling associated to the effective four point interaction of the electroweak interactions},
symbol={\ensuremath{G_F}},
user1={${1.1663787(6)\times 10^{−5}~\text{GeV}^{-2}}$}
}
\begin{document}
We use \glssymbol{fermiconstant} which is the \gls{fermiconstant}.

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols,style=symval]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful! I'm going to give it a shot - Thanks!

Comment: And Happy Holidays!

Comment: @MKF thanks, happy holidays to you too :)

Comment: Can I ask a quick question Marjin? What if you have other entries without this style? Can you combine them into one glossary?

Comment: I'm not fully sure but I think the style is per glossary - which makes some sense, it would be strange if there are different layouts in a list of symbols for example. However, as you may have seen from the example code, there are macros like `\ifglshasfield{user1}` that do a different thing if the field is found for an entry (i.e., print the field) or when a field is not found (do nothing in this example, i.e., `{}`, but it could also be some default text for example). So you may be able to use this to combine different types of entries nicely in one glossary.

Comment: Or of course make multiple glossaries with different styles, for example one for symbols with values, and another with binary relations or something.

Comment: Wow that is excellent, I'm going to try that macro for sure, thanks again for your insight!